# Working on eTA for a non-Canadian company

Tags: canada, work, eta

I’m a Polish national working remotely as a freelancer for a US company. Would I be in violation of eTA rules if I continued working during my visit to Canada? Do I need to declare it? (Assume that my trip will take place after all COVID-related restrictions are lifted)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is allowed.  Canada is unusual in adopting such a modern approach to the question.

The government of Canada has a [page](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/temporary-residents/foreign-workers/what-is-work.html) discussing the definition of *work* in the context of work visas, which explicitly lists as an example of an activity that is "not considered to be 'work'"

> long distance (by telephone or Internet) work done by a temporary resident whose employer is outside Canada and who is remunerated from outside Canada;

I would not declare it unless you are asked a question that can't be answered straightforwardly without mentioning it, or unless you're planning such a long visit that the question is inevitable.  (Exactly how long that is probably depends on your circumstances.)

Comment: That is the most amazing common sense approach that I have ever seen!